# A different statement of the Chinese remainder theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, chinese-remainder-theorem

My professor gave us a statement for the "Chinese Remainder Theorem" different from that stated in David M. Burton, which say:

If $n_1,\dots,n_k$ are coprime positive integers, then there exist a ring isomorphism $g:\mathbb Z_{n_1\cdots n_k}\to\mathbb Z_{n_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb Z_{n_k}$.

And he defined it as: $$g(a\bmod n_1\cdots n_k)=(a\bmod n_1,\dots,a\bmod n_k)$$.

Then he proved that this function is well-defined, which I did not understand it, could anyone show me this proof please?

Comment: Please elaborate on precisely what you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: The proof of well-definedness of this function ....... I want to see it please @BillDubuque

Comment: Please state the proof and identify the step that you did not follow.

Comment: I only wrote after my professor this $$ a -  y = nk = n_{i} (?) k$$, where $n = n_{1} .... n_{k}$ @BillDubuque  ............. which I do not understand at all.

Comment: We need more context. Is the argument that $\,y\equiv a\pmod{n}\,\Rightarrow\, y\equiv a\pmod{n_i}\,$ for all $i?\,$ Do you know how to prove that, and why that shows that $g$ is well-defined?

Comment: No I do not know why that shows that $g$ is well-defined.@BillDubuque  ..... for the first part yes I understand it

Comment: You need to show that the definition of $g$ does not depend on the choice of rep in the equivalence class $\ a\bmod n = a + n\Bbb Z,$ i.e. that the map yields the same value if you instead choose $\,a'\equiv a\pmod{n}\,\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call $m=n_1\cdots n_k$. If this function $g$ is to be well-defined, then $g(a+\ell m)$ must be componentwise equivalent to $g(a)$. That is, for each $1\le i \le k$, we must have 
$$a+\ell m \equiv a\pmod{n_i}.$$
However, $n_i\mid m$ so that $\ell m\equiv 0 \pmod{n_i}$ for each $i$. Thus, indeed $a+\ell m \equiv a \pmod{n_i}$. This shows well-definedness.

Maybe its also a good idea also to provide an explanation for why one must actually check that functions are "well-defined" at all. We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ consists of quotients of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. However, the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are actually equivalence classes of pairs $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ subject to $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if and only if $ad-bc=0$. (This is the notion of *equivalent fractions* taught in primary school.) Suppose now we define a "function" $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\frac{a}{b}\mapsto a$. To ensure that this function is well-defined, we need to be sure that it is independent of the choice of representation of $x=\frac{a}{b}$. However, $x=\frac{2a}{2b}$ also, so that per our recipe $x\mapsto 2a$ also. Thus, this function is *not* well-defined. So a naïvely defined "function" on $\mathbb{Q}$ may not be a function at all.

Comment: I know that proving well-definedness means showing that the definition of the  function is independent on the representative but why in our case this is proved by showing that $g (a + lm)$ is componentwise equivalent to $g(a)$, Is this because of the congruence relation and the cosets? but if so could you elaborate this a little further please?

Comment: I added some more information on this.

Comment: In the line before last, do you mean $ x \mapsto \frac {2a}{2b}$?